# In C#, why does using dynamic type allow me to use operators on generics?

Tags: c#, generics

In class we have being dealing with generics and were asked to complete an assignment.

We created an `Account<T>` class with one property `private T _balance;` and then had to write methods to credit and debit `_balance`.

`Credit method` (partial) called from Main by e.g. `acc1.Credit(4.6);`:

```
    public void Credit(T credit)
    {
        Object creditObject = credit;
        Object balanceObject = _balance;

        Type creditType = creditObject.GetType();
        Type balanceType = balanceObject.GetType();

        if(creditType.Equals(balanceType))
        {
            if(creditType.Equals(typeof (double)))
            {
                 balanceObject= (double)balanceObject + (double)creditObject;
            }
       ...WITH more else if's on int,float and decimal.
        }
        _balance = (T)balanceObject;   
    }
```

I had to condition check and cast as I cannot `_balance += (T)balanceObject;` as this will give the error `"Operator '+' cannot be applied to operand of type 'T'"`

During my reading on the subject I discovered the `dynamic` type. In my new Account class I added a new method and changed the `Credit` method to: (called from Main by e.g. `acc1.Credit(4.6);`)

```
    public void Credit(dynamic credit)
    {
        _balance += ConvertType(credit);
    }
    public T ConvertType(object input)
    {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(input, typeof(T));
    }
```

This is what I don't understand. The credit method takes in the object as type `dynamic` and the `ConvertType(object input)` returns it as type `T`. 
Why does using dynamic type allow me to use operators on generics?

Comment: Did you run it yet? The `dynamic` keyword will delay (defer) the type checking that the compiler normally does until you actually run the program.

Comment: Cheers. The program runs fine. Also adding to my confusion was the method `ConvertType` which allowed me to throw number strings at my generics e.g. `acc1.Credit("100");`. So I was starting to have some strange ideas about `generics`. As soon as I read `defer`, Eureka!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using `dynamic` types, resolution is deferred until runtime. If, at runtime, the generic type supports a `+` operator, your code will work. If not, it will throw an exception.

From a [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) article on `dynamic`:

> At compile time, an element that is typed as dynamic is assumed to
>   support any operation.